# Why does MinGW GCC tolerate missing return types even with `-pedantic-errors`, unlike regular GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc

Here's the code:

```
main() {}
```

On [gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tLgAZSW9ABk8tTADljAI0zFBAB1QLC62nsMTT29fOlt7JyNXd05FZUxVPwYCZmICAONTTgslFTU6ZNSCcMcXN0EFFLSMoNjKopLI6K4ASkVUA2JkDgByI2Y7CBaAanEAdlkxgBEettYQHoBWHtJTHrMV1AWdOTlhhQ6uzFHJAGZOFYIFjZa2gGsQbgAOADon08WnyTMngE5FxaSM6/IQLbgrNYbUhbHorBQgCxXdazUhwWAwRAoVBGDx4dhkCgQNA4vHlYDZWJUPEENzwiDOa4rZx2VIATwWF1IxKMWgIAHlaKx2cjSFh%2BqJ2IzRXhiAk1AA3TDwkWYAAeCQMNI5KzsNPmItYeGcxDZeiw2tIBGIeCM2raNHoTDYHE4p34gmEohQuxkQiN8NgtGYPJAVCMBFIivcPQAbJILrdoR58rRlQBaADqbFYw0zaqtzFzHkw6BEamQabcxBIClzlXQ4lOUwkMjk3zh8USGggVhqWUs2kaZRipC8PhTfeC478Q6i5TqnZThWq%2BkyFUXSSqxTspTnI/qK8C/YP24iw9a7U63Qv%2BuWqylMNVTxjaZj3GGwGQyGG2RenGGEC4IQJAnOcpDDHoJL4qBnAjDsrYyJcjKJvq4KkLanCcC8AIfGYManGYZhjNwbqQpsCxwgilrIaiGIQEgHQEB4mrkJQxK4vigglsBI4OowLCStkpAAO4mh4dqgksEIPgsUjnMMwmEAgwxPi%2Bb4fl%2BP5mH%2BSHIihYIrLa5x/twvycIsZncNwnAxoRiz3iKMKUYiNFopi7GkgSbHYhx5TIJ65KERYVKsDSxB0gyIrMkGxDCpy3K8gKQpSmKIjAJKIr4LKiSKsqUJqhqWo9JyurKFKhrGqaGC9JyVo2hJfFOoJboCJIQhpd6CHyBVAZQEGIZhhGUYLHGCZtKgyZ%2BOmWasDmeaqgWRYlmWeAVlWNZ1gQDZNi2sgyO2cR5H4mjaJOsRWLOzSxGOoT%2BKutSjiEKaXfOh1ypuRRnW9Xa0Mup67ldihbl9J4vTEbQHFeLpzAsd5kdCCyqa%2B77%2BWlWkvNpZgAUBRDEDB4GQb5eNyZIcE%2BtIuk3DDPRoRhWGYb8PwxmMZiLMR5lPLw8NOYoVFIjctHwPRICMcxEaEh5nFtdxuOCI1AkuhYonMOJxUore0mObJZySApSkqc%2ByPDKjojo5jlOzNTtOPDGf5jF83D26ZHyLKcMYOVCPPwi5en3CAiz02%2BnBjGZZhWWMYwxrE%2BqnJrnsUdRvuSZIcfkbCidU5GtLHdwQA), both GCC 10.1 and Clang 10 (with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -std=c++20`) refuse to compile this.

GCC: `error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'main' with no type [-Wpedantic]`
Clang: `error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations`

But on my local machine, MinGW GCC happily accepts this code without any errors or warnings (with the same flags). This is not something new; this specific peculiarity was there for years.

Why does MinGW GCC behave differntly from the regular GCC in this case? Are there any flags to make it diagnose this error?

I got my GCC from MSYS2. It identifies as

```
# g++ --version
g++.exe (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) 10.1.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Clang 10 on the same machine does reject the code (the official binary, using libstdc++ from this GCC).

Comment: Is MinGW GCC actually a (prob. shell script) wrapper around an actual GCC? Then it might be mangling the options/passing ones that override yours.

Comment: @HTNW I'm using Windows, so there's no other GCC for it to wrap. No, it's not a shell script. `g++` is `g++.exe`, a binary.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you compile with `g++ -v -Q` in both cases, do you see any notable differences?  This dumps the list of options in use, including those set as defaults when the compiler was configured and installed.  It also itemizes all enabled code gen options (`-f*` and `-m*`), though sadly not the warning options, which is what would be nice here.

Comment: @NateEldredge I don't see anything interesting in there. https://www.diffchecker.com/PhTjHzxb (godbolt gcc on the left, mingw on the right)

Comment: What about in the preceding "options passed" section?

Comment: @NateEldredge `-iprefix ... -D_REENTRANT 1.cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -std=c++2a`

Comment: Okay, I guess that doesn't help.  Sorry.

Comment: @NateEldredge Don't apologize. At least now we know the difference is not in the flags.

Comment: MinGW is different because it by default enables [-fms-extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#index-fms-extensions-1). This allows implicit int, apparently for MFC. Compile with `-fno-ms-extensions` and the result should be the same.

Comment: @ssbssa Yep, this is it. I suggest posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [noted by @ssbssa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62850909/why-does-mingw-gcc-tolerate-missing-return-types-even-with-pedantic-errors-u#comment111184590_62850909), MinGW GCC enables `-fms-extensions` by default, and it's one of the effects of that flag.

Compile with `-fno-ms-extensions` to fix that.